# Syntax error when checking value of variable

Tags: ansible

This should be a very simple task but I'm unable to get past a syntax error.

In the below playbook, the first task gets the capabilities of Python and registers it in `python_capability` where `python_capability.stdout` becomes `/usr/bin/python3.10 cap_sys_nice=ep`.

In the next task, I split this string and set `capabilities` to everything following after the 0th item. In this case, `capabilities` becomes `[cap_sys_nice=ep]`.

Then, I want to check the length of the above list and fail if it's `> 1`.

```yaml
- hosts: tests
  become: yes

  pre_tasks:
    
    - block:

      - name: Ensure Python has CAP_SYS_NICE privileges
        capabilities:
          path: /usr/bin/python3.10
          capability: cap_sys_nice+ep
          state: present
        register: python_capability

      rescue:

        - name: RESCUE | Get Python capabilities
          set_fact:
            capabilities: "{{ python_capability.stdout.split()[1:] }}"

        - name: Get length
          set_fact:
            num_capabilities: "{{ capabilities | length }}"

        - name: Failed when 
          failed_when: num_capabilities | int > 1
```

But I get the below syntax related error:

```
ERROR! no module/action detected in task.

The error appears to be in '/test.yml': line 25, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


        - name: Failed when
          ^ here
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `failed_when:` is an attribute of an existing task, not an action on its own, so you likely want [`assert:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) or to move that `failed_when` to the `set_fact:`, which would be kind of weird but legal

Comment: Also, you cannot expect that the tasks in the rescue block would have `python_capabilities` defined and containing valuable information if the task indeed failed and made you end up in the rescue block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the last task to:

```
- name: Validate number of capabilities 
  ansible.builtin.fail:
    msg: "There are too many capabilities"
  when: num_capabilities | int > 1
```

This will stop the execution if the condition is met.